# Use jquery to select submit button in rails 3

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

At the moment I am just trying to get jquery to show an alert when my submit button is pressed in my form, I have given it an id

```
<%= submit_tag "search", :id => 'submitForm' %>
```

and tried this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#submitForm').submit(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
 alert('clicked');

 });
});
```

but i get no alert, I have also tried

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(':input#submitForm').submit(function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
  alert('clicked');

 });
```

});

but this doesnt work either..is there anything i am doing that is obviously incorrect

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The submit event can only be attached to forms, not to submit tags. You need to put the ID on your form.

```
<%= form_tag "/", id: "submitForm" do %>
  <%= submit_tag "search" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: yeah that works :), but what if i have two forms in one form controlled by one submit button, use the same class on each form?

Comment: You should never use the same ID more than once on the same page.

Comment: yeah i thought so, class name it is then or just two different ids

Answer (score 1):

`submit` event is fired for form elements, not submit buttons, as your element is an input/button element with type of submit, you should select your form element instead:

```
$(function(){
   $('#theForm').submit(function(e) {
      // ...
   });
});
```

Comment: could i use a click event instead then?

Comment: @Richlewis Yes, you can use click event. Just replace submit with click in your code.